# Processing a 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Hello so far I have figured out a simple technique for only manipulating the odd rows in my array

```
int[][] myArray = new int[rows][cols];

for (int i = 1; i < rows; i+=2)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)     
        myArray[i][j] = 1;
```

Below is my desired output which works great

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I now need to get my 2D array to match this styling below but I am having trouble doing so. Any suggestions?

```
[3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3]
[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Fill first row and last row then write 0 on odd row and odd column? From there filling even column will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int rows = 10, col = 11;
int[][] myArray = new int[rows][col];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){   
    if((i == 0 || i == rows - 1) && (j == 0 || j == col - 1)){
        myArray[i][j] = 3;
    }
    else if ((i + 1) % 2 == 1 || i == rows - 1){
      if((j + 1) % 2 == 0)
        myArray[i][j] = 1;
    } else{
      if((j + 1) % 2 == 1)
        myArray[i][j] = 2;
    }
  }
}
```